# I deleted pulse audio folder and now no sound what to do

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm new to the Linux world and chose Ubuntu as my daily driver. My sound and everything was going fine when i ran this command in terminal and made my life a mess
: The command- pulse audio -k
After that i saw a blog saying i should delete my Pulse folder in etc and I did that. Now my sound i.e both my output and input are gone please help me get my sound back !
I get this error when I run pulse audio --start
**E: [pulse audio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.**
Please please help me

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to get a better idea how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

Yipee I got the solution
solved this issue by deleting ~/.config/pulse followed by a reboot.
So in summary, running these commands solved all my audio problems after a few weeks of debugging (so stupid if you see it now, but whatever works right?)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol
sudo alsa force-reload
```

reboot

Comment: After some system enforced wait time, you can accept your own answer by marking the checkmark below the vote count.  Glad you found the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall pulseaudio
```

to recreate the deleted folder `/etc/pulse/` and it's content.

Comment: Hello @mook765 I did as you told and it has been created successfully,but the folder from home/user/ was also deleted . How do I solve that

Comment: There is no way to recreate the content of `~/.config/pulse/` since this files were created by you. So only you know the content of these files and you have to recreate them in the same way you created them the first time. When you want to try something and need to remove a file to do that, make a backup of the files you are going to delete first. Another option (for files in your home directory) is to move the files to trash instead of deleting them, so you could easily restore them if needed.

Comment: Hey, I didn't  create them it was the files of the pulse audio itself and I dont know what it contains, Will copying the files from a live environment to my profile work ?

Comment: @mook765 That folder was more likely created and populated by the Ubuntu installer -- configuring pulseaudio for the hardware and drivers it had found during installation.  It may be necessary to reinstall Ubuntu to recreate this process, though I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Now what do I do.

Comment: If the user has a backup they could reload the ~/.config/pulse/ from there. If they do not have a backup...2nd lesson learned from this episode.

Comment: Hey Organic Marble, I dont have any sort of backup But cant i use the live boot folder and paste it here ?

Comment: I do not know the answer to that.

Comment: Someone please help me ! I really need to overcome this

Comment: I believe just running pulseaudio will create some files in `~/.config/pulse`, if you never added any file there by yourself, you shouldn't worry, pulseausio will create the necessary files itself. Are you able to start pulseaudio now?